Filtering of keys of nested objects
I am trying to filter the keys of objects which are empty(i,e with value '') and if there is nested object with keys  empty that should also get filtered. The method i am using is filtering keys at parent level but not in nested objects
input
obje = {
  a:'a',
  b:'',
  c:'c',
  d: {
    e:'e',
    f:'',
    g:'',
    h:''
  }
}

output
obje = {
  a:'a',
  c:'c',
  d: {
    e:'e',
  }
}

filterKeys(obj: any) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => {
      return typeof value !== 'object'
        ? value !== ''
        : this.filterKeys(obj[key]);
    }),
  );
}

with the above method i am getting output
obje = {
  a:'a',
  c:'c',
  d: {
    e:'e',
    f:'',
    g:'',
    h:''
  }
}

not sure why it is not filtering inside nested object
